# Mark is_read in Notification system with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a site where users can post things like statuses, pictures, etc. I'm wan't to create a notification system similar to Facebook . Something that alerts the user of their friends recent activity. My problem is i'm not sure how I should structure my table. I'm following some advice from an older tutorial [Tutorial](http://codegains.com/2014/06/laravel-4-notification-system/) for the db scheme, and doing something like this

**id | user_id | subject | body | object_id | object_type | is_read | sent_at | created_at | updated_at**

I know what to do for the majority of the code, or at least have a good idea, my problem and question is for the is_read column, should i create a separate table to store that information, if not then how can I mark a notification as is_read with the current setup.

Comment: Why should you make a separate table? How did you come to this idea?

Comment: Once you load the message for the user.. simply mark the is_read column as true/1?

Comment: this table is for all users to pull from, all users that are friends with that user. So all users that are friends will be pulling the notification from that one row. So i can't just mark is_read on that table because more than one user will be pulling from it @Farkie

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have a "is read" for **EVERY** friend/user, this was a bit unclear. If this is the case your best bet (in my opinion) would be to create a new table, as you said, containing the post_id, and user_id. All you then have to do is to check is such a relationship exists, and if so, show a notification.

Comment: Yes, I want to have a is_read for every friend. The table that you say i should create, is that also where i should put the is_read column, along with the post_id and user_id?

Comment: Well, all you need is the user id and the post ID. Then, if the user has read the post, just delete it from the table

Comment: Except you want to show old notifications too, then you need a is_read column which you then have to update

Comment: so when I query the notification in laravel psedecode  example: Notification::where()->userisfriends()->get() , how would i check the is_read table to see if the user has already read that notification: example: i have  an is_read table columns post_id | user_id | is_read and the values are 1 | 18 | 1 , post id:1 user_id: 18 and is_read is 1 , how would i write a query to grab that info so that i could then display it in the view. Many users will be grabbing from a single  notifications column,ex: If i post something all my friends see that notification @Manuel Mannhardt

Comment: //Notifications already read by Auth::user()
    public function unreadNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications()->wherePivot('read', false)->get();
    }

    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('PMS\Notifications', 'read_notifications', 'id', 'notification_id');
    } @Manuel Mannhardt would something like this work?